# Java PrintWriter not writing to file

Tags: java, file-io, printwriter

In this program I'm reading a file full of numbers, adding them to an array, and calculating the minimum, maximum, sum, and average of the values, then writing those values to a text file.  I'm reading the values into the array and calculating fine, but my writing method isn't working properly.

Writing method:

```
public static void write(File file, int min, int max, int sum, double average){

    try{
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("file");
        pw.println("The min value is "+min);
        pw.println("The max value is " +max);
        pw.println("The sum of the values is "+sum);
        pw.println("The average of the values is "+average);
        pw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Failed to write to file");
    }

}
```

Initializing the method:

```
int min = min(data);
    int max = max(data);
    int sum = sum(data);
    double average = average(data);
    File stats = new File("stats");
    write(stats, min, max, sum, average);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing your `PrintWriter` with the filename `file` instead use:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
```

That will create a file named stats.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I did that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The program is checking for a file named "file".You need to pass an Object of `java.io.File`

```
public static void write(File file, int min, int max, int sum, double average){

    try{
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
        pw.println("The min value is "+min);
        pw.println("The max value is " +max);
        pw.println("The sum of the values is "+sum);
        pw.println("The average of the values is "+average);
        pw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Failed to write to file");
    }

}
```